# Dynamically change the height of one div based on another div

Tags: html, css

[Small Demo of My situation](https://jsfiddle.net/k59ukenj/2/)

**My CSS**

```
  .left
 {
  width: 30vw;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  min-height: 80vh;
  float: left;
 }

 .right
 {
  min-height: 80vh;
 }
```

How do i change the height of left div and it's margin, based on right div?

Answer (score 1):

Only  `CSS`

```js
var str = "Cricket Australia chief executive James Sutherland and Bangladesh Cricket Board president Nazmul Hassan have different opinions over who made the decision to postpone Australia's tour of Bangladesh";
    
    $('.addContent').click(function(){
        $('.right').append(str);
        
    });
$('.addContent').click();
```

```css
.main {
    display: table;
}
.left
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
    width: 30vw;
}
.right{
    display: table-cell;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div class="left">
        <input type="button" class="addContent" value="add">
    </div>

<div class="right">
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code in your javascript
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/L0jn3pvf/)
(

```
$(function(){ var str = "Cricket Australia chief executive James Sutherland and Bangladesh Cricket Board president Nazmul Hassan have different opinions over who made the decision to postpone Australia's tour of Bangladesh";

$('.addContent').click(function(){
    $('.right').append(str);
    $('.left').height($('.right').height());  
});

$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
$('.addContent').click();
});
```

And change your css like below

```
.left
{
border-right: 1px solid;
height:100%;
width:20%;
float:left; 
}

.right
{ 
  float:right;    
  height:100%;
  width:79%;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```js
var str = "Cricket Australia chief executive James Sutherland and Bangladesh Cricket Board president Nazmul Hassan have different opinions over who made the decision to postpone Australia's tour of Bangladesh";
    
    $('.addContent').click(function(){
        $('.right').append(str);
        
  $('.left').height($('.right').height());        
        
    });
$('.left').height($('.right').height());        
$('.addContent').click();
```

```css
.left
{
    width: 30vw;
    border-right: 1px solid;   
    float: left;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
        <input type="button" class="addContent" value="add"></div>
    </div>

<div class="right">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var height = Math.max($(".left").outerHeight(), $(".right").outerHeight());
            $(".left").height(height);
            $(".right").height(height);
        });
```

So whatever dinamic content you have you'll add both containers the highest `height`... however you need to float the right one so the script get the right height (with the overflowed content) and give it a fixed width. I added `border-box`so margins and borders won't bother.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/k59ukenj/5/)**